# Where do I ask a question regarding selecting products/ tools?

Tags: discussion

I have to create complex graphs and am wondering about different platforms to use - chart.js (limited) v d3.js (which may be a bit much).  Plus more specific questions such as ability to do x, y and z.

**Is that a question for stackexchange or some other place?**

Comment: We have [a brand new site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) for that. Join the fray :) (but be sure to read their [quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information))

Comment: The real answer is to create a prototype of each, see which one suits you better, and use that.

Comment: Frederic - awesome. Thx.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi never link to the main page, link to the guidelines instead.

Answer (score -1):

Yep these types of questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow, but thanks to a new beta site, you can ask them at [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) site. SR has strict requirements for how to ask a question there, so please read the linked page thoroughly before submitting a new question there.